# repeat html element with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i would like to repeat my panel element from bootstrap in my `for loop` and display my variable `mysubject` in my panel title.

For example. if my `data.tickets.length == 4` i should have 4 panel element and every panel got a different title. Can you help me i don t know how to repeat my panel element. I just manage to set the title so far.

Here is my code :

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-3 panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function displaytickets(){
    var y = document.getElementById("mySecond").value;

    $.ajax({
      url: "https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/"+y+"/tickets/requested.json",
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType:'application/json',
      secure: true,
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("claire.pagniez@cubber.com:"));
      },
      success: function (data) {
          console.log(data.tickets.length);
          for (i = 0; i < data.tickets.length; i++) {
              console.log(data.tickets[i]);

              console.log(data.tickets[i].description);
              console.log(data.tickets[i].status);
              console.log(data.tickets[i].subject);
              var mysubject = data.tickets[i].subject;

              $(".panel-title").append('<h3>'+mysubject+'</h3>');
          }
      },
  });
}
```

Comment: .panel-title is already an h3 tag why are you appending h3 tag inside it?

Comment: Just to be sure you are right it is not mandatory :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .clone(), and you can create your panel directly from jQuery like this:

```
var $panel = $('<div/>').addClass('col-xs-3 panel panel-default');
$panel.append($('<div><h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3></div>').addClass('panel-heading'));
$panel.append($('<div>Panel content</div>').addClass('panel-body'));
$('body').append($panel);
```

or you can `clone()` and existing element like this:

```
var $panel = $('#my-panel').clone();
```

and then clone it again to get each new panel. 
Inside your .ajax() call:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.tickets.length; i++) {
    var new_panel = $panel.clone(); // note the use of .clone()
    new_panel.find('.panel-title').text(data.tickets[i].subject);
    new_panel.find('.panel-body').text(data.tickets[i].description);
    $('body').append(new_panel);
}
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/uxo27cq0/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi to repeat your panel div depending on length of data you can first clone the panel object(div tags + inner text + headers etc) you want and append it to the parent of the first panel . In this way you can save appending the html using strings in jquery.

Or if you want to use data in each panel specific to you can go with string appendign.

```
success: function(data) {
    var tickets = data.tickets;
    for (var i = 0; i < tickets.length; i++) {
        var panelBody = "";
        panelBody += "<div class=\"col-xs-3 panel panel-default\">";
        panelBody += "  <div class=\"panel-heading\">";
        panelBody += "    <h3 class=\"panel-title\">" + tickets[i].subejct + "<\/h3>";
        panelBody += "  <\/div>";
        panelBody += "  <div class=\"panel-body\">";
        panelBody += "    Panel content";
        panelBody += tickets[i].status;
        panelBody += tickets[i].description;
        panelBody += "  <\/div>";
        panelBody += "<\/div>";
        $('.panel-default').parent().append(panelBody);
    }
}
```

You can also insert the data which you want to show in the panel.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
success: function(data) {

    console.log(data.tickets.length);
    for (i = 0; i < data.tickets.length; i++) {

        $(".panel-default").parent().append('<div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">' +
            data.tickets[i].subject + '</h3></div><div class="panel-body">' +
            data.tickets[i].description + '</div>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 success: function (data){
               $.each(data.tickets,function(i,v) {
                 $('body').append('<div class="col-xs-3 panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">'+v.subject+'</h3></div><div class="panel-body">Panel content</div></div');
                });
    }
```

note: change `body` to your parent list of tabs